# iMacros: form filling THEN extracting the results

Tags: forms, csv, imacros, extract

I've searched through previous questions but can't seem to find the advice I'm looking for.

I'm currently testing a quote engine in a web based testing environment, which involves filling in different criteria (Location, Age, Dates), pressing submit and then being presented with the results in a table.

It's taking FOREVER, so I'm trying to automate the process in iMacros.

I've successfully setup a macro to pull out the criteria I need in the form from a csv file and fill the form, but now I need to extract the data for each time the form 'fills' itself.

Is this actually possible?

Here's my code so far....

```
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE returndates.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=XXXX/TravelQuotation
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:Aggregator CONTENT=%engine1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:TripType
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:TripArea CONTENT=%2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:--<SP>Select<SP>One<SP>--
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:StartDate CONTENT=01/03/2014
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:EndDate CONTENT=02/03/2014
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:GroupType
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:FirstName CONTENT=John 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:LastName CONTENT=Smith
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:Email CONTENT=john.smith@smithjob.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=ID:PrimaryTravellerDOB CONTENT=30/03/1965
TAG POS=9 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:TravelQuotation/RetrieveQuotes ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:Product<SP>Name<SP>Product<SP>Type<SP>Max<SP>Days<SP>Premium* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=TEST1.csv
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

possible. 
Use EXTRACT command
Here is the link:
http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction